# python. get size of an object

Tags: python

I need to know size of objects in my python program.
I have `for` loop in which I need to know size of objects.
If I use `sys.getsizeof` then memory does not free instantly
and I cannot see actual size. Is there way to do it?

My objects are json and string. In the worst case I can 
save them to file and look at file sizes. But how can I look
at file size from python code?

**Edit**: size of serialised objects is more important for me.
so second part of the question is essential.

Thanks.

Comment: The size of a file (representing the serialized form of an object) on disk does not necessarily correspond to the amount of memory occupied by the corresponding object. _Why_ do you need to know the size? Are you concerned with memory consumption? What is the larger problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this information?  There might be a more streamlined path to your goal.

Comment: What do you need this for? There are several kinds of "sizes".

Comment: I have json and text in my program. I need compare sizes of these two.

Comment: @capoluca you didn't answer their questions. _Why_ do you need the sizes?

Comment: You need to compare the string length?  The number of elements?  What?

Comment: I need compare size in bytes. I am creating algorithm that saves json's, this is the bottle neck of my program. I need to know how much I will be better if I store json's compare to text. (I got this json from processing the text)

Comment: Is it not 8 bits per character?

Comment: @skyl, quite possibly not.  Lots of people use UTF-8, which has variable length (in bits) characters.

To the OP, if you are trying to benchmark the sizes for optimization purposes, why not just write the data out to a text file and a binary file, then see which is bigger?

Comment: @sr2222 yes I can do it for one or two files, but I also need to gather statistics on 1000 files. how to do that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Considering that `type(json.dumps(something))==str` you should be able to literally just use `len`.

Consider the following

```
obj = {'content' : 'something goes here'}
json_obj = json.dumps(obj)
json_size = len(json_obj)

serialized_size = len(serialized_object)

if json_size < serialized_size:
  print "I'd use the JSON with this..."
```

Comment: I'd like to follow up with this since I posted this in 2012. This is applicable to python 2.7. In Python 3 strings inherently support unicode characters and therefore it is not safe to assume that the `len(str_object)` is equal to the number of bytes since unicode characters are not necessarily 1 byte each. In python 3 you can do `len(json_obj.encode("utf-8"))` which should be the number of bytes.

Comment: Very likely the serialized object will also be encoded as utf-8. If the data is in ASCII, or mostly the same in both formats, the original advice is not only useful but still pretty accurate. Nevertheless, I hope this can get updated to provide the true length in bytes. I'm not quite knowledgeable enough to propose an edit though.